# How do I know what I am signing on handheld digital stylus signature devices?

Tags: contract-law, signature

I'm talking about the handheld signature devices that the UPS guy has, or the credit card POS system that stores have you sign with the stylus on when completing a return.

It's always a completely blank white screen with the whole screen reserved for a signature. It always bothered me that I have to sign, but there isn't even a hint of what exactly I am signing. When I ask the employee it's always some generic answer, "You're signing that you received the package", or "You're signing that you returned this item".

Are these signatures even legally binding, given that I don't even know where to find the contract's terms if I wanted to?

Comment: If you actually wanted the terms, you would presumably ask the person requesting your signature in firmer terms for a copy, to which they would direct you via either a template card or the website of the person they represent.

Answer (score 2):

You are not agreeing to anything - all the signature does is provide (really good) evidence that you and the pad were at a particular place at a particular time. If another person (like the courier who owns the pad) says they were there too and gave you a package it would be virtually impossible for you to prove that you *didn't* get the package. That's what the signature is for.